# Android onCreate pause before continuing until class loads

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

So I haven't had any luck trying to find a solution to my problem.
Here is what it is going on and I'm hoping that maybe someone can help me:

I have a class called purchasedItems that loads the IabHelper and loads the in-app items purchased by the user. This class handles everything that has to do with in-app purchases.

When a certain activity launches, I have the class purchasedItems initialized in the activity's onCreate() method. However, it seems that it takes about 2-3 seconds for the purchasedItems class to finish loading or getting all of the in-app purchases to figure out which ones the user paid for or not.

I want during the onCreate() method in the activity to initialize the purchasedItems class and wait until it is done before continuing loading everything else in the activity. I'd like to have a progress dialog box to pop up when it starts loading the purchasedItems class and go away once the purchasedItems class is done loading.

Again, the purchasedItems is just a class that does not extend to anything. All it does is initialize the IaHelper in order to manage in-app purchases, etc.

I have not had any luck with this, so please can someone help me?
Thank you
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't find what I think it is a proper solution to the problem above. What I ended up doing was to initialize the IabHelper object and then added a 2-3 second post delay before executing any more code. This allows IabHelper to be initialized and have 2-3 seconds to finish doing whatever it has to do before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `AsyncTask`. That would let you do your loading on a background, and would then notify the UI thread when it was done. In `onCreate()`, you'd open up your progress dialog, then run a loop waiting for the background thread to finish. It would looking something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // do various things
    LoadStuffTask t = (LoadStuffTask) new LoadStuffTask().execute(); // launch the background task
    // pop up your dialog box
    while(t.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
    {
       // wait on background thread
    }
    // task finishes, close your dialog
}
```

Your `AsyncTask` subclass could look like this (generic implementation - you could have different return types if you want):

```
protected class LoadStuffTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) // your background thread calls this method
    {
        // do your loading
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void v) // this method is called when doInBackground returns - once it finishes, the AsyncTask will have its status set to FINISHED 
    {
        // up to you if you want to do anything here
    }
};
```

One important thing to keep in mind is that you should never try to access the UI from `doInBackground()` because it does not run on the UI thread. If you want to get fancy and show a perentage of purchases that have been loaded (if known), you can use the `publishProgress()` method of `AsyncTask`, which triggers a call to `onProgressUpdated()` on the UI thread, where you **can** access the UI (e.g. to update a progress bar or something).

Another thing to beware of is possible hang of your main thread if the task never completes, so you should guard against that (perhaps with a timeout).

Documentation for the `AsyncTask` class is found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: On second thought... blocking the main thread waiting for the task isn't too much more useful than just doing it on the main thread directly. You might be better off just doing that, unless you're planning on having something happen concurrently on the main thread.